# How to invoke asynch Operations after synch Operations with Quarkus Smallrye Mutiny?

Tags: java, quarkus, mutiny, smallrye

I need to run some synchronous code followed by asynchronous code in Quarkus. The documentation sounds promising https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/2.2.0/guides/imperative-to-reactive/, but it seems to be dated since Uni.createFrom() doesn't return a Uni but an UniCreate object and some method names seem to have changed since the recording of the Quarkus Insights talk.

I've tried several variations without success. It sounds like the method 'transform' could help, but I haven't found samples how to use it in this context. Other options return "thread must not be blocked".

I'm looking for something like this:

```
public Multi<MyReponseMulti> queryAsStream(String query) {
    return Uni.createFrom().
        item(() -> {
            MyReponseUni myResponseUni = this.invokeRemoteServiceUsingBlockingIO(query);
            return this.invokeRemoteServiceUsingReactive(myResponseUni);
        });
        .runSubscriptionOn(Infrastructure.getDefaultWorkerPool())
        .subscribe().asCompletionStage();
}
```

Right now the code above has a compilation error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from CompletableFuture<Multi<MyReponseMulti>> to Multi<MyReponseMulti>
```

Could someone please help? Thanks!

Comment: I need more detail. First, you return a Multi, while subscribing to the method (hint: never subscribe yourself, only 1% of the use case requires that). Also, `Uni.createFrom() has always returned a `UniCreate` instance. What is the return type of `this.invokeRemoteServiceUsingReactive(myResponseUni);` and `invokeRemoteServiceUsingBlockingIO` ??

Comment: Thanks Clement!
I used runSubscriptionOn because the doc suggests it.
this.invokeRemoteServiceUsingReactive(myResponseUni) returns Multi<MyReponseMulti>; this.invokeRemoteServiceUsingBlockingIO(query) returns MyReponseUni.

Comment: I still don't understand. In your code snippet you return a Multi (in the signature) but the code seems to only use Uni. Can you describe what you are trying to achieve? The runSubscriptionOn is correct if the supplier is blocking. So, maybe what you want is `Multi.createFrom().deferred(() -> ... )`

Comment: Thanks Clement, I want to return Server Sent Events to an API client which returns Multi<OutboundSseEvent> based on Multi<MyReponseMulti>. This works nicely if I only call this non blocking code. However, before I run the reactive code I need to invoke a blocking operation invokeRemoteServiceUsingBlockingIO. The output of the blocking operation is the input of the reactive operation. I would think this is a typical scenario. Would be great if you could help!

Comment: Here is my current attempt: https://github.com/nheidloff/question-answering/blob/56fe86c0474720f9fb39f9619baa8e735de5b022/service/src/main/java/com/ibm/question_answering/QueryDiscoveryMaaS.java#L42

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need something like this:

```java
public Multi<MyReponseMulti> queryAsStream(String query) {
    // First, create a Uni for the blocking operation
    var blockingOp = Uni.createFrom().item(() -> {
      return this.invokeRemoteServiceUsingBlockingIO(query);
    }).runSubscriptionOn(Infrastructure.getDefaultWorkerPool());
    // Now, transform the outcome of this uni to the Multi 
    return blockingOp
       .onItem().transformToMulti(myResponseUni -> {
            // I guess this method returns a Multi
            return this.invokeRemoteServiceUsingReactive(myResponseUni);
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Clement! Works!